# SQL query not working with jQuery AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql

I am using jQuery to post 2 variables. Then I load an external php file to put those 2 variables in the database. For some reason the query doesn't work. If I try it the normal way. It works.

jQuery code

```
    $.post("/include/getResult.php", { 
finalscore:score, finalcredits:credit },
 function(data){

console.log("Data: " + data);

});
```

PHP code

```
session_start();
$finalscore = $_POST['finalscore'];
$finalcredits = $_POST['finalcredits'];
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT score,credits FROM gebruikers WHERE leerlingennummer = '".$_SESSION['leerlingennummer']."'");
if(mysqli_num_rows($query) == 1)
{
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
    //get the current score and credits
    $score = $row['score'];
    $credits = $row['credits'];
    $score = 'succes';
}
echo $score;
```

For some odd reason the query doesn't work this way.

Comment: SQL query **cannot** work or not work with jQuery AJAX. They never meet. It's *PHP* that runs your query, not AJAX

Comment: "SELECT score,credits FROM gebruikers WHERE leerlingennummer = '".$_SESSION['leerlingennummer']."'"  SQL injection attracts

Comment: @YourCommonSense I see that PHP runs the query. But AJAX calls the PHP file. If I load the php code the normal way it works. But via jQuery it doesn't work

Comment: @TimLuigjes can explain $_SESSION['leerlingennummer'] use? When you set this session variable?

Answer (score 0):

PHP CODE

```
session_start();
$finalscore = $_POST['finalscore'];
$finalcredits = $_POST['finalcredits'];
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT score,credits FROM gebruikers WHERE leerlingennummer = '".$_SESSION['leerlingennummer']."'");
if(mysqli_num_rows($query) == 1)
{
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
    //get the current score and credits
    $score = $row['score'];
    $credits = $row['credits'];
    $score = 'succes';
}
echo $score;
```

AJAX

```
$("YourSubmitButtonId").click(function(event){

    event.preventDefault();

     var Formdata = $("YourFormId").serialize(); 

        $.ajax({

        type:"POST";
        url:"/include/getResult.php",
        data:Formdata,
        success:function(response){

        $("reponceId").html(response);

        };




    });
});
```

Comment: `SELECT score,credits FROM gebruikers WHERE leerlingennummer = '".$_SESSION['leerlingennummer']."'"` SQL injection _attracts_

Comment: The inputs taken from a form, or otherwise entered by a user should be sanitized before being used in a query, is a serious security problem. You should use prepared statements.

Comment: he used his codes.I love to work with PDO with prepared statement

Comment: I got the data from the form into the php file. The thing is the query doesn't seem to work when using jQuery. It works when I use it without jQuery.

Comment: Can you edit your html,php full code ...did u insert jquery library

Comment: try to execute the query without parameters so you can see where is the problem. You can also print $_GET and $_POST array in a file to see what jQuery pass to php script.

Comment: @SamithaHewawasam Other jQuery functions are working fine. The PHP code is working in the normal way (without the use of AJAX).

Comment: Do you using a submit button to send data ? then use event.preventDefault() to prevent the reload of the page>i'll update the code...

Comment: Now u should get the data from the php page

Comment: @lucky88 The query is just fine. I execute it in phpmyadmin and I get the result I want.

Comment: @SamithaHewawasam there is no need to use a submit button. The post data is working fine. It's about the query for php

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work well. But you need to add/modify some code.

1. For prevent SQL Injection

   ```
   $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT score,credits FROM gebruikers WHERE leerlingennummer = '".$_SESSION['leerlingennummer']."'");
   ```

   should be

   ```
   $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT score,credits FROM gebruikers WHERE leerlingennummer = '".addslashes($_SESSION['leerlingennummer'])."'");
   ```

   - $_SESSION['leerlingennummer'] can be blanked. Review your code.
2. Add update query

   ```
   if(mysqli_num_rows($query) == 1)
   {
       $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
       //get the current score and credits
       $score = $row['score'];
       $credits = $row['credits'];
       $score = 'succes';
       mysqli_query($con, "update gebruikers set `score` = '".addslashes($_POST['finalscore'])."', `credits` = '".addslashes($_POST['finalcredits'])."' where leerlingennummer = '".addslashes($_SESSION['leerlingennummer'])."'");
   }
   ```

This code will modify score in mysql to 'finalscore', credits in mysql to 'finalcredits'.
Than, ajax alert will be 'succes'. If you want to be a score before update, you can do like this:

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($query) == 1)
{
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
    //get the current score and credits
    $score = $row['score'];
    $credits = $row['credits'];
    mysqli_query($con, "update gebruikers set `score` = '".addslashes($_POST['finalscore'])."', `credits` = '".addslashes($_POST['finalcredits'])."' where leerlingennummer = '".addslashes($_SESSION['leerlingennummer'])."'");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but if anyone has a similar issue, be sure to check that the file your ajax is calling includes all the (PHP) functions that your original file uses. It's easy to miss the little errors sometimes :)

And use Event Delegation where it concerns the jQuery functions.